# Access two dashboards with same url path using single domain name in treafik

Tags: traefik, api-gateway, traefik-ingress

I am using [traefik](https://allanjohn909.medium.com/kubernetes-ingress-traefik-cert-manager-letsencrypt-3cb5ea4ee071) for accessing my dashboards.

But the issue is that I have some dashboards that call the same paths internally.
For ex:

- dashboard1 => /apis/v1/services
- dashboard2 => /apis/v1/services

In this case how to use the same domain name for these two dashboards?

Also, some dashboards use different paths internally like the following:

- dashboard3  =>

  ```
             /logo.png
             /user/login
             /umi
             /vendor
             ...
  ```

I am able to access these dashboards using separate domain names.

- dashboard1.demo.com
- dashboard2.demo.com
- dashboard3.demo.com

So I want to use the same domain name as `dashboard.demo.com` for all these dashboards.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For a more user-friendly way, I would suggest to use PathPrefix (see [Router Rules] at https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule) to distinguish between your Dashboards. E.g.:

- `https://dashboard.demo.com/dashboard1/apis/v1/services`
- `https://dashboard.demo.com/dashboard2/apis/v1/services`

For your services to keep working properly you need to rewrite the paths back using Middleware [StripPrefix](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/stripprefix/) or [StripprefixRegex](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/stripprefixregex/).

An other non user-friendly way might be using Header based routing.

Comment: But the APIs (`/apis/v1/services`) are called by the dashboards internally after clicking on some tabs on the dashboard.  So it is still possible to use StripPrefix or StripprefixRegex to rewrite the paths from `/apis/v1/services` to `/dashboard1/apis/v1/services`.

Comment: It depends on the dashboard application. If the dashboard uses relative paths it should work. Most applications allow adding a base path in config to address issues like yours. If it doesn’t and uses a absolute path, it will break. As there seems to be no way to distinguish between the dashboards (e.g. specific query params, specific headers) your only option Leitwolf be usage of (sub)domain per dashboard.